# Illustrator: Make a bracket with lines of different widths

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to make a bracket like this, but the longer, top line should be slightly thicker than the vertical, shorter lines. This seems surprisingly hard:

- I cannot align the lines of different width using smart guides (and/or changing the stroke settings below), it's offset and if I match 'manually', resizing the thing changes the relative positions
- Starting out with a square with stroke and no fill, I can easily get
  the result below (leaving out bottom, longer line), but fail at isolating the lines (without changing them) to change their widths individually.

This drives me crazy, I hope whoever reads this can empathize... any help or advice welcome

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have one path with multiple stroke widths.  You can create a stroke with varying width for one path, but it won't work for this.

Try this instead: Do *Object > Expand* to expand the stroke to a filled shape, then select two anchors and nudge them with the arrow keys, while counting how many you nudged it by. Repeat for the other side.

Example

[image]

Comment: It *could* be done with stacking width points, similar to stacking gradient color stops for a hard edge. But.... it's really a *nightmare* to try and control the Width Tool that way, *especially* on corners.

Comment: @Scott -there are many ways this could be done, but since the OP has already created a stroke, this is a simple method to continue from that point.

Comment: I agree and +1'd already `:)`

Comment: ow. I seemed completely off track with this one, thank you. So, the upshot is, this approach is much more feasible than multiple line objects, correct? +1 from me too, obviously

Comment: @user2305193 This is just one simple method starting from a stroke. But there are also other possible methods. For example, using the pen tool and a grid, or doing a unite boolean operation on some rectangles, or a difference boolean operation, or using the shape builder tool, etc, etc.

Comment: THeres even more options. Don't make it one line! make it 3 lines than you can set widths toe ach segment. If Cap is set to projecting cap it works as expected

Comment: @joojaa can you put this into an answer? The cap setting just didn't work for me, it was always offset...